# Excel Macro to ping IP from a cell

Tags: excel, vba, cmd

I've created an excel inventory of all of my network devices, what I'd like to do is have a macro that allows me to ping the IPs of these devices with a single click. I got somewhat close with this VBA script:

Sub RunCommand()
Dim cmd As String
cmd = "ping "
Call Shell("cmd.exe /c " & cmd, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub

The issue is I'm looking for a way for the macro to add the value of the selected cell as the address to ping, so the final command should be "ping [cell value]" but I can't figure out how to make that happen.

Created and tested the VBA script

```
Sub RunCommand()
    Dim cmd As String
    cmd = "ping "
    Call Shell("cmd.exe /c " & cmd, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Which works but requires each cell value manually entered one by one.

Did attempt this variation of the script

```
Sub RunCommand()
    Dim cmd As String
    Var = Range("b2").Value
    cmd = "ping "
    Call Shell("cmd.exe /c " & cmd, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

However wasn't able to get that to work

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```vb
Sub PingCheck()
    Dim resp As String, c As Range, v
    
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A10")
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            resp = ExecShellCmd("ping " & v)
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = resp
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Public Function ExecShellCmd(FuncExec As String) As String
    ExecShellCmd = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
                    .exec("cmd.exe /c " & FuncExec).stdout.readall
End Function
```

EDIT: use of event to trigger ping

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim v
    
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub 'restrict to (eg) Col A...
    v = Target.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ExecShellCmd("ping " & v)
        Cancel = True   'don't enter edit mode
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why running `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` with option `/c` just to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe`? Why is __PING__ not executed directly?

Comment: that's pretty close and does work, although this pings every single IP in my list. What I was hoping for is to click the cell with the IP I want to ping and have it just ping that address. Thanks for assisting though!

Comment: You could use either the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event to trigger the ping.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by using this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim IP As String
    IP = Target.Value
    If IP Like "*.*.*.*" Then
        Shell "cmd.exe /k ping " & IP, vbNormalFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

which looks to see if the text in the selected cell matches an IPv4 address then runs a ping. Thanks again for the help!